# Shopify change product template via API

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

I try to update product template via Product API. I retrieve product list, iterate over it, change **template_suffix** property and update product.

When I retreive products again I can see that it was changed **template_suffix** property, but when I look at this product using Shopify admin, I see that in dropdown list nothing was changed and in preview also.

Is it possible to change product via Product API, and what do I do wrong?

Comment: Try to get the template suffix from Shopify itself first; probably will be in Shopify handle format - `{{ template }}` will give the exact name that shopify stored it as. Use whatever it is after "product." and before ".liquid" and update it exactly the same way. It should work. Just did the same thing yesterday.

Comment: @HymnZ Thank you. You relly helped me. I was a liitle bit confused format "template_suffix" from API. "The suffix of the liquid template being used. By default, the original template is called product.liquid, without any suffix. Any additional templates will be: product.suffix.liquid."